# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint [Laravel 7.0]

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Hi i continue getting this error when i try to migrate my migration on laravel i've tryed every suggestion that i've seen online,

The error is this SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `settoris` add constraint `settoris_stock_code_foreign` foreign key (`stock_code`) references `prodottis` (`codice_stock`))

I got this migrations, i don't know what i am doing wrong i'm using laravel 7 and php 7.4

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProdottisTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('prodottis', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('codice_prodotto');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('codice_stock');
        $table->date('data_di_scadenza');
        $table->decimal('costo', 10, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('prodottis');
}
}
```

And this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSettorisTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('settoris', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('stock_code');
        $table->string('settore');
        $table->string('scaffale');
        $table->integer('quantita_rimanente');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    schema::table('settoris', function($table){
        $table->foreign('stock_code')->references('codice_stock')->on('prodottis');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('settoris');
}
}
```

Comment: You must define primary key column in `references` `$table->foreign('stock_code')->references('codice_stock')->on('prodottis');`

Comment: You need to migrate `prodottis` table, before `settoris` table.

Comment: @Shahrukh i've done that,

Comment: @EsTeAa it migrate prodottis before settoris

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your foreign key to reference to `codice_stock` columns which is not a `primary` key. You can make it `primary index` like this:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('codice_stock')->primary();
```

And with this you will get another error! That's because you can only have one primary key. So you might delete `id` from `prodottis` table.